# Probability of $10$ random balls filling $7$ bins. Does indistinguishability matter?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I saw this solution to a problem in my textbook:

The problem is we have $10$ indistinguishable balls and $7$ distinguishable bins. What is the probability of having at least one ball in each bin?

From what I saw in [Probability: Distinguishable vs Indistinguishable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935922/probability-distinguishable-vs-indistinguishable), I think it is false to calculate the number of sample space elements like

${7+3-1 \choose 3} = {9 \choose 3}$

since then we would miscalculate the probability.

I think we should consider the balls distinct then solve it by means of Stirling number of second kind. Am I right?

Comment: No, you’re not right; the balls are indistinguishable, so you you want $\binom93$.

Comment: but if $\binom93$ right then if we calculate the probability of exactly one head and one tail in a toss of two Indistinguishable coins in the same manner we would get 1/3 which is wrong !?  i mean in calculating this problem if we put number in balls and then calculate the probability we get a different resualt which i think is the right resualt .

Comment: the questions says we randomly put the balls into the bins.

Comment: It would have been nice if randomly put the balls into the bins had been fleshed out. For example, randomly put is consistent with the additional rule that there are no more than $2$ balls per bin. However, under the most natural interpretation (thrown one at a time, with all bins equally likely, and outcomes independent) the natural sample space has $7^{10}$ equally likely outcomes. We can count the outcomes where each bin has at least one by Inclusion/Exclusion (Stirling) or, since $10$ is not much bigger than $7$, by cases.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I really wish that books wouldn't use the word "indistinguishable" to refer to balls that are actually distinguishable.  It seems likely that the intention of the author was for the problem to be done the way that the OP /  André Nicolas suggest, but that method assumes distinguishable balls.  It's not clear how indistinguishable balls would actually behave - this is important for answering probability questions, and the book says nothing about it - but a good guess would be that they behave like bosons in quantum mechanics.

Comment: [Bose-Einsten condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose–Einstein_condensate#Einstein.27s_non-interacting_gas) is a non-classical phenomenon which occurs precisely because of the indistinguishability of the particles.

Comment: Note to the OP: in a system of three bosons, each of which can be in two possible states - this is the indistinguishable analog of the coin-flipping problem - the size of the sample space would be 3, not 4.

Comment: Yes, that is an interesting example. But in standard ball/bin applications, such as caching, the filling of bins is by a process that produces (for our ridiculously small numbers) $7^{10}$ equally likely outcomes.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: So in these applications, "indistinguishable" means "not distinguished but capable of being distinguished if we wanted to" rather than "incapable of being distinguished"?

Comment: That is a good way of putting it. Indistinguishability, with the Physics exception you noted, is relevant to counting, but much less often to proability.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the formula $${7+3-1 \choose 3} = {9 \choose 3}$$ miscalculates the required probability is not that it confuses the distinguishability or indistinguishability of the balls, but that is treats each distribution of the balls in the pins as equally likely, although this is not true. For a thorough explanation see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986482/different-approaches-to-n-balls-and-m-boxes-problem).

Comment: What other distribution can it be then?

Comment: @David: I think that Stefanos's remark is consistent with the method in your answer.  You treat the $7^{10}$ ways of placing $10$ distinguishable balls in $7$ distinguishable bins as equiprobable.  If the distinguishability of balls is ignored, then the number of placements reduces to $\binom{9}{3},$ which are no longer equiprobable.  For example, the configuration $(4,1,1,1,1,1,1)$ with balls indistinguishable corresponds to $10!/4!$ configurations with balls distinguishable, whereas the configuration $(3,2,1,1,1,1,1)$ with balls indistinguishable corresponds to $10!/(3!2!)$ ...

Comment: ... configurations with balls distinguishable.

Comment: I should clarify that my attempt at explanation of Stefanos's answer is not meant to support the idea of treating indistinguishable objects as though they were distinguishable.  See my comments to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how the bins are filled with the balls so I will assume randomly.  I am also assuming that each of the $7$ bins can hold all $10$ balls if need be.  Using a "brute force" case method, there are $3$ main ways to fill all $7$ bins.  We already know each of the $7$ bins must contain one ball, then the remaining $3$ balls can be placed as follows:

case 1: $1$ bin has $4$ balls and all the others have $1$ ball each.  Ways of that happening are $7 \choose 1$.

case 2: $1$ bin has $3$ balls, another bin has $2$ balls, and all the others have $1$ ball each.  Ways of that happening are $7 \choose 1$ * $6 \choose 1$ which is also $7 \choose 2$ * $2$.

case 3: $3$ bins have $2$ balls each and the others have $1$ ball each.  Ways of that happening are $7 \choose 3$.

The numbers of ways to place $10$ balls in $7$ bins is $7^{10}$.

So the probability is the sum of cases $1,2,$ and $3$, divided by # of ways,  so we have $\frac {7+42+35} {282,475,249}$

Comment: You are assuming distinguishability of both balls and bins when you compute the denominator, but only of bins when you compute the numerator.  If you account for distinguishability of balls in the numerator, you will be computing $S(10,7),$ the Stirling number of the second kind, which was the suggestion of the OP.